# How to access Warden current user in business logic in Rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, warden

I am using [Rails Warden](https://github.com/hassox/rails_warden) plugin. It defines a [helper method](https://github.com/hassox/rails_warden/blob/master/lib/rails_warden/controller_mixin.rb) 'user' that returns current user. See the link for the source code.

Now I have an business logic object that does not have any reference to the controller. But I would like to get the current user. Is there any way of accessing this?

I have tried

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.user
```

or even

```
RailsWarden::Mixins::HelperMethods.user
```

with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to get acces from model?

Comment: No, from a object that has only static methods. These are called from a controller.

Comment: Did you try `include Rack::Test::Methods`? https://github.com/hassox/rails_warden/wiki/Troubleshootings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I have an business logic object
>   that does not have any reference to
>   the controller. But I would like to
>   get the current user. Is there any way
>   of accessing this?

So why can't you just pass the current user to those methods?

Additionally you can mix them in.

I strongly discourage you to write the static helpers (it is not Java, it is Ruby!).
Instead, where you need those helpers include them as a module:

```
module SuperLogic
 def calculate_stuff(current_user=nil)
  (current_user || user || self).bills.sum
 end
edn
```

Then include this where you need it:

```
# user model
class User
  include SuperLogic
  #it will get the `calculate_stuff` method
end

# controller
include SuperLogic
# so you can use it as one of
calculate_stuff user
calculate_stuff
```

and so on...

additionally where you access your business logic, you can just create an instance of the class instead of "static" methods (in ruby they are "class" methods):

```
# controller
def calculate
  @result = BusinessLogic.new(user).calculate_stuff
end
```

This is probably the easiest thing you can do.

Really, you don't need to access whole HTTP context in your business objects (I'm not even talking about testing it).

Comment: Thanks. I have used this: http://github.com/bokmann/sentient_user
http://github.com/astrails/let_my_controller_go
http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models

Answer (score 0):

The way I think of business logic, it's something that sits between the controller and the model. I think it would be ok to pass an instance of the request to the logic methods, and since you're using warden, you can get the user from 'request.env['warden'].user'.

I haven't encountered a good reason not to have logic methods be static (self.) methods of a module. Maybe Dmytrii's suggestion works for you, but I prefer to 'require' than to dynamically include one-off logic bits.